# Large Print Font in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, font-size

I am trying to get large-print in R Markdown (Anything 16 point or bigger) when it knits to PDF. From the YAML, I know I can do `fontsize = 12pt` and this can take 10pt, 11pt or 12pt options. Additionally, I know there is the `extarticle` class option in LaTeX so that I can get above 17pt font. Is there a way to combine the two so that I can get large font using the R Markdown system and knit it to a PDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the two options you mention in your YAML header:

```
---
documentclass: extarticle
fontsize: 17pt
[...]
---
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I greatly appreciate it.